# Halcon: Obtain how much is a mm in pixels after calibration

Tags: halcon, hdevelop

I've successfully calibrated my camera and I can get the dimensions of a XLD in world coordinates with `ContourToWorldPlaneXld` and then `HeightWidthRatioXld`. This returns me the measures of a contour extracted from a shape.

Now I need to convert a value inserted by the user in mm (example in mm: 0.1) and get how many pixels the measure is, for example, to draw a line.

I need the pixel value as per request. I tried looking around in the Halcon documentation but I didn't find what I was looking for.
Also I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066938/halcon-inverse-of-image-points-to-world-plane) but it' not exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm using Halcon Progress 21.11.

**Edit:** A possible solution could be obtaining the dimensions before converting them to world plane and then do something like `pixel/world` but I would prefer a better method if it exists.

Comment: To me it seems, that the answer you are referring to is an answer to your question. Could you explain how is this different?

Comment: @VladimirPerković yes, if you are referring to the edit I made. It is working and seems pretty accurate. In my question I was wondering if there was a dedicated method in Halcon to transform a measure from and to pixel given the camera parameters and pose, similar to what ContourToWorldPlaneXld does for example

Comment: I don't think there is a direct method in Halcon.